# Jquery Clone direct children of element only

Tags: jquery, clone, children

I am trying to clone the first level of an unordered list **only** and not any children beyond that. My list is as follows.

```
<ul class='leftNav'>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>C<ul>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
    </li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

I am using the following to clone list items but this is cloning everything:

```
var leftNav = $(".leftNav").children().clone();
```

What I would like is just this:

```
<li>A</li>
<li>D</li>
<li>C</li>
<li>D</li>
```

Is this possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
var leftNav = $('.leftNav > li').clone().find('ul').remove().end()
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rd44fqxw/)**

Answer (score 0):

You will need first to add all the li (with there sub-ul) , then find "ul" and remove it :

```
var leftNav = $(".leftNav").children().clone();
leftNav.find("ul").remove();
$(".clone").append(leftNav);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/952acm99/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var leftNav = $(".leftNav").children().clone().find('*').remove().end();
```

Example on jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rcjwv0ez/